# Function taking any object as parameter

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-parameter

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class A
class B

def foo[A](x: A) = typeOf[A] match {
    case x:A => println("this an A")
    case _ => println("no match")
  }
}
```

But this will prove useless as no match is possible, I get:

```
fruitless type test: a value of type runtime.universe.Type cannot also be a A
```

I would like to have `foo` take any `type` of class, from basic types to custom classes. How would I do that?

Comment: case x:Int => println("this an Int") dont you think you follow this

Comment: a typeOf[A] is not A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ClassTag` the following way to make it happen

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def foo[A: ClassTag](x: A) = x match {
  case x: A => println(s"this an ${x.getClass}")
  case _ => println("no match")
}
```

`A` can be any type.